# Organizing two related lists into chunks

Tags: python, list

I have a list of data `data = [ x1, x2, ..., xn ]` and the corresponding labels of this data `labels = [l1, l2, ..., ln]`. I want to organize this two related list such that it is split into equal sized chunks for example for `sizeChunk = 3` we have `data = [ [x1, x2, x3], ..., [xi, xj, xn] ]; labels = [ [l1, l2, l3], ..., [li, lj, ln] ]`. This is easy using the following function:

```
def chunks(data, labels, sizeChunk):
   chunks_data = [data[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(data), sizeChunk)]
   chunks_labels = [labels[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(labels), sizeChunk)]
   return chunks_data, chunks_labels
```

However, what I want is more complicated. Suppose that we have only 4 possible values that the labels can take: 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D', that is `setPossibleLabels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`. I want that the first chunk contains only the data labelled with 'A', the second chunk contains only data labelled with 'A' and/or 'B', the third chunk will contain data labelled with 'A' and/or 'B' and/or 'C', ... and so.

In other words, for this example, the data of type 'A' can appear in any chunk, the data of type 'B' can appear in any chunk except the first one, the data of type 'C' can appear in any chunk except the first and the second chunks, the data of type 'D' can appear in any chunk except the first and the second and the third chunks.

Is it possible to do that easily in Python ?

**EDIT: Example:**

input:

```
data = [ x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11 ]
labels = [ 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A' ]
setPossibleLabels = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ] # same as list(set(labels))
chunk_size = 3
```

expected output is for example:

```
chunks_data = [ [x1, x5, x8], [x2, x11, x3], [x7, x9, x4], [x6, x10, x11 ] ]
chunks_labels = [ ['A','A','A'], ['B','A','B'], ['C', 'C', 'B'], ['B', 'C', 'A'] ]
```

Comment: Expected output for this: `list('AABBCCCCCCDDDDD')` for chunk_size = 3?

Comment: @hcwhsa as input you have two lists `data` and `labels` and the value that each label can tale is in the set `setPossibleLabels`.

Comment: You should add some examples in the question body.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why don't you just organize all your data in a dict with label as key? Then you can do `if x in chunks['A'] or x in chunks['B']: ...`

Comment: @SteinarLima I'm not sure you understood my question, please chuck the example of input/output that I just added to my post

Comment: @hcwhsa I added example, please check it

Comment: @shn Will there be any case like chuck_size = 5 but number of `'A'`s are just 4?

Comment: @hcwhsa yes but if the number of A is less than 5 and the chuck_size = 5, then it is allowed to put some B in the chunk of A to complete its size to 5.

Comment: Your rules are not very well defined and require a lot of special handling for edge cases. The question regarding to few elements is just a nice example. Try to write down what you exactly want to do in pure words. Do you still think, there can be a simple straight forward solution?

Comment: @Achim just check the comment on top of yours, I said that in case of too few elements if is allowed to have other type of elements in the chunk to complete its size.

Comment: Example, a possible expected output for list('AABBCCCCCCDDDDD') when chunk_size = 3, is just [ ['A','A','B']['B','C','C']['C','C','C']['D','D','D']['C','D','D'] ]

Comment: @shn How did you end up with `['B','A','B']` as the second list, it should be `['B', 'B', 'B']` if I understood it correctly?

Comment: As usual, it'd be helpful if you wrote down an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version of your algorithm -- however inefficient -- which does *exactly* what you want, especially in corner cases.  Then we can make suggestions about how to improve it without spending time guessing your answers to the kinds of questions that @hcwsha is raising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty ugly, but it should work.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat    
data = range(0,12)
labels = [ 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C' ]
setPossibleLabels = [ 'A', 'AB', 'ABC' ]
chunk_size = 3
chunks_data = []
chunks_labels = []

for label in chain(setPossibleLabels, repeat(setPossibleLabels[-1])):
    chunks_data.append([])
    chunks_labels.append([])
    for index in range(chunk_size):
        i = 0
        try:
            while labels[i] not in label:
                i += 1
        except IndexError:
            break
        chunks_data[-1].append(data.pop(i))
        chunks_labels[-1].append(labels.pop(i))
    if len(data) == 0:
        break

print chunks_data
print chunks_labels
```

Which yields:

```
[[1, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6], [4, 7, 9], [10, 11]]
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Is this the expected output? Since `len(data) == 11`, the last chunk is of length 2.

Comment: Aside: your `gen` is `itertools.repeat`, I think.